# I get true though the @if() query is not true Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want **users** with a specific package

```
$silver = User::where('package_id', '2')->get();
```

And this brings me back

```
  Collection {#329 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

and when I examine

```
@if($silver)
something
@endif
```

return true **HOW??**

How to make this system work?? And if return the user's which is not logged again is true.

Comment: One ? is fine. Two or more is getting ridiculous. What are you confused about here? If `$silver` is a list, why wouldn't the `if` expression be logically true?

Comment: `$sliver` exists and is an object => `if` returns `true`, so what's wrong? Which system do you want to make work? Please define expected behaviour first.

Comment: should explain it: https://3v4l.org/S28Ke

Comment: Moreover, you already asked the same thing in the other question you posted. Note, that you completely ignored the comments in the first question.

Comment: I want to make a system which will be based on the user's package have certain profile editing capabilities?

Comment: are you looking for `@if(count($silver))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps when you get a empty object, it could be true on blade template

Try it:

```
@if($silver->count() > 0)
something
@endif
```